# What's the best way to load c libraries into Ruby for ffi on OSX?

Tags: ruby, macos, ffi, aspell

I'm trying to use [`ffi-aspell`](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ffi-aspell/) on OSX

Right now, the code fails as it can't find `libaspell.so.15`, because it's named differently in homebrew and paths are different:

```
/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'aspell': dlopen(aspell, 5): image not found. (LoadError)
Could not open library 'libaspell.dylib': dlopen(libaspell.dylib, 5): image not found
```

So after a bit of digging, I've found a few examples on Github of people checking for hombrew being installed, then looking for a path that way.

I ended up with something like this which works for me:

```
module Aspell
  extend FFI::Library

  begin
    stdout, stderr, status = ::Open3.capture3("brew", "--prefix")
    homebrew_path  = if status.success?
                      "#{stdout.chomp}/lib"
                    else
                      '/usr/local/homebrew/lib'
                    end
  rescue
    # Homebrew doesn't exist
  end

  ffi_lib ['aspell', 'libaspell.so.15'] if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
  ffi_lib ["#{homebrew_path}/libaspell.dylib"] if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
```

This feels like a fairly hacky solution.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: If your code works and you want to find out how to improve it then consider moving it to [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm talking about approach rather than code